# Doing ssh to through java

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I want to execute this command through a java code
ssh abc@ubuntu

I am using this code but it doesn't work completely, it doesn't log in to the server.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class JavaApplication4 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ssh","usmanmahmood@ubuntu");
//pb.redirectErrorStream(); //redirect stderr to stdout 
Process process = pb.start();
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

    int waitFor = process.waitFor();

   } 


   }
```

Please tell me the mistake,

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Consider using Jsch:  http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: @Collin, there is no error msg this is the output
usmanmahmood@ubuntu's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-17-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

257 packages can be updated.
59 updates are security updates.


and it stuck here

Comment: No, I don't want to use jsch, What my basic purpose is to ssh to ec2 instance on aws. and after that run a java code there,

Comment: Can any one tell me what is wrong with the code, and provide me with a code which will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're waiting for a `null` line from your `Reader`, but you're never going to get that from an open SSH session.

In your case, `ssh` is waiting on you at the command prompt of the remote server, and you're waiting on `ssh`.

Try adding the command you want to run to the options passed into ssh. It'll just log in an run it.

A perhaps more relevant question though is, why are you doing this in Java? Why not just write a shell script?

Comment: Thanx so much for your help, I am doing it through java because my teacher said me to do it.....

Comment: SO, you mean to say that I cannot log in through java code? 
I have changed that while loop to while (count<9)
It still gets stuck at the same point

Comment: You can, but your code is waiting for a session to close, which won't happen unless you close it. You need to either run the `ssh` command in such a way that it runs your remote program when it logs in, or you need to parse the response from the server, figure out when SSH has logged in, and write the command yourself.

Comment: Judging by what you put in your output, your code _is_ logging in correctly, but you're not giving ssh anything to do once it does.

Comment: How can I close it ?? 
My basic purpose is to run a java file on ec2 instance via ssh, and I have to do that through java code, so for that I am trying to do this... 
If you can tell me the way to do that then I will be much thank full to you

Comment: Can you correct my code so that it just logs in, and shows that it is logged in.... 
because when I type "abc@ubuntu" after some lines which I have posted above, it says "Last log in at -----------"
But when I run my code, these lines don't come...
abc@ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

You might be running it from windows machine? And ssh is not a valid command for windows unless you have added it specifically. Most people will advise to use JSCH http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html

Comment: No, I am not running it from windows machine, I am running it from linux machine, Ubuntu

Comment: @user2061477 : as Collin mentioned you can have a shell script which will ssh and execute another shell script on remote machine. Java is not required for this. You may cron the script file on local machine which will execute at a particular interval.